# how to write regex pattern.finditer into a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, csv, python-re

I am trying to write a regular expression to select the text I want from a corpus, and then write the extracted text into a dataframe in CSV format.

Here is the code that I used:

```
import re

import pandas as pd

def main():

    pattern = re.compile(r'(case).(reason)(.+)(})')

    with open('/Users/cleantext.txt', 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        matches = pattern.finditer(content)
        for match in matches:
            print(tuple(match.groups()))


    # Create a DF for the expenses
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tuple(match.groups())])

    df.to_csv("judgement.csv", index=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

However the CSV would only return one line of output:

```
,0,1,2,3
0,xxx,yyy,zzz,}
```

where I was expecting multiple lines since the corpus contained at least 100 judicial judgements.

the orginal corpus looks something like this:

```
{mID a9d50454f624         case xxx reason yyy judgement zzz}
{mID a9d5049e34e934bff9b  case xxx reason yyy judgement zzz}
{mID a67c9e34e934bff9b    case xxx reason yyy judgement zzz}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to get the two substrings denoting `case` and `reason` from each match.
You can use

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'\bcase\s*(?P<Case>.*?)\s*reason\s*(?P<Reason>.*?)\s*judgement')
matches = [x.groupdict() for x in pattern.finditer(content)]
df = pd.DataFrame(matches)
```

Note the named capturing groups are used to automatically create a column name, the `x.groupdict()` returns a tuple containing the group name and its value.
The `[x.groupdict() for x in pattern.finditer(content)]` returns a list dictionaries that can be used to populate the dataframe.

You can also use

```py
matches = pattern.findall(content)
df=pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['Case', 'Reason'])
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VgAQWr/1). *Details*:

- `\bcase` - a whole word `case`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?P<Case>.*?)` - Group "Case": zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*reason\s*` - `reason` word enclosed with optional whitespaces
- `(?P<Reason>.*?)` - Group "Reason":  zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*judgement` - zero or more whitespaces and then `judgement` string.

Comment: your second method worked very well! thank you so much!